# EF Class table name and column have same name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework and I have the modelbuilder iterate over my entities to create them. The problem is that one of the tables I want to read from is named the same and one of the columns. This cant work since the class is the same name as the property.

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Role{ get; set; }
} 

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (Type entityType in GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(entityType);
    }

    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid having the table and the attribute the same name as it is redundant. You should be able to read the code naturally. Instead of `RoleId`, I'd just use `Id`, and instead of `Role` I'd use `Name`. You already know the table you're accessing because it's usually exposed on the model.

It'd be more natural to access:

`dbRepository.Role.Name`

Than:

`dbRepository.Role.Role`

---

Anyways, try something like this:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Role{ get; set; }
} 

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("MyCustomRoleTable");   

    foreach (Type entityType in GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(entityType);
    }

    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way could be using [ComponentModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema?view=netframework-4.8)'s [ColumnAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute?view=netframework-4.8), rather than overriding OnModelCreating.

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }

    [Column("Role")]                //Actual database column
    public string Name{ get; set; } //Name it whatever is more readable.
}
```